# Visual Code Integrated Terminal messed up

Tags: windows, visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-code

I clicked something which I have absolutely no clue of and now every-time I click on 'New Terminal', I am being presented with an external PowerShell window rather than the integrated terminal. Any clue how to set it correctly (or should I say more aesthetically)?

**Current Situation:**
[image]

**Expected:**
[image]

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the program, no change.

Comment: you have a drop-down in your integrated terminal. What options do you have there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved by unchecking *Use Legacy console* in PowerShell
[image]

Current State:
[image]